# how i use smart pointer in template?

Tags: c++, codeblocks, dev-c++

i am using with template but i have a problem to convert edible or beverage in my restaurant project to item in template?? somebody know how to do it??
the beverage and edible are  inherits from item 
or if someone have any idea to improve my project thnks for any help

```
#ifndef NODE_H
#define NODE_H
#include "Item.h"
#include "Edible.h"
#include "Beverage.h"
#include "Special.h"
enum Type { special ,beverage, edible };
template <class T>
class Node
{
    public:

        T* _item;
        Node* _next;
        int _refCount;
        Node():_next(NULL),_refCount(0),_item(NULL){}
        Node(T* item,Node<T>* next):_next(next),_item(item),_refCount(1){}
        ~Node(){    if(_item)delete _item;_item=NULL;}

        friend ostream& operator << (ostream& os,const Node<T>& node){    if(node._item)return  os<<*node._item;else return os<<"";}
        Node<T>*   getNode(int i);
        double getPrice()const {return _item->getPrice();}
        void addRefCount()  {_refCount++;}
        void addNode(Node<T>* newItem);
        void print();
        template<class newType> // template function for
        operator Node<newType>() // implicit conversion ops.
        {
            return Node<It>(this);
        }
        int removeItem(){return --_refCount;}
    private:
};

template <class T>
inline Node<T>*  Node<T>::getNode(int i)
{
    Node<T>* current=this;
    for(i;i>0;i--)
        current=current->_next;
    return current;
}

template <class T>
inline void Node<T>::addNode(Node<T>* newItem)
{
    if(newItem==NULL)
        return;
   newItem->_next=_next;
   _next=newItem;

}
template <class T>
inline void Node<T>::print()
{
    Node<T>* head=this;
    /*Print all item until we have null*/
    while(head!=NULL)
    {
        /*Check if there is any item inside*/
        if(head->_item!=NULL)
            cout<<*head->_item<<endl;
        head=head->_next;
    }
}

#endif // NODE_H
```

i have a problem with this function: `inline Node<T>*  Node<T>::getNode(int i)`

```
#include "Menue.h"

Menue::Menue():_headEdible(NULL), _headBeverage(NULL),_headSpecial(NULL)
{

}

void Menue::printMenue()
{

    _headEdible->print();
    _headBeverage->print();
    _headSpecial->print();

}


void Menue::deleteItem(Node<Edible> *item)
{
    if(item==NULL)
        return;
    if(!(item->removeItem()))
    {
        Node<Edible>* current;
        current=_headEdible;
        if(_headEdible==item)
            _headEdible=_headEdible->_next;
        else
        {
            while(current!=NULL&&item!=current->_next)
                current=current->_next;
            if(current==NULL)
                return;

            current->_next=current->_next->_next;
        }
        delete item;
    }
}


void Menue::deleteItem(Node<Beverage>*  item)
{
    if(item==NULL)
        return;
    if(!(item-> removeItem()))
    {
        Node<Beverage>* current=_headBeverage;
        if(_headBeverage==item)
            _headBeverage=_headBeverage->_next;
        else
        {
            while(current!=NULL&&item!=current->_next)
                current=current->_next;
            if(current==NULL)
                return;
            if(item!=current->_next)
                return;
            current->_next=current->_next->_next;
        }
        delete item;
    }
}

void Menue::deleteItem(Node<Special>*  item)
{
    if(item==NULL)
        return;
    if(!(item-> removeItem()))
    {
        Node<Special>* current=_headSpecial;
        if(_headSpecial==item)
            _headSpecial=_headSpecial->_next;
        else
        {
            while(current!=NULL&&item!=current->_next)
                current=current->_next;
            if(current==NULL)
                return;
            if(item!=current->_next)
                return;
            current->_next=current->_next->_next;
        }
        delete item;
    }
}






Menue::~Menue()
{
    while(_headEdible!=NULL)
        if(!(_headEdible->removeItem()))
        {
            Node<Edible>* temp=_headEdible->_next;
            delete _headEdible;
            _headEdible=temp;
        }
    while(_headBeverage!=NULL)
        if(!(_headBeverage->removeItem()))
        {
            Node<Beverage>* temp=_headBeverage->_next;
            delete _headBeverage;
            _headBeverage=temp;
        }
    while(_headSpecial!=NULL)
        if(!(_headSpecial->removeItem()))
        {
            Node<Special>* temp=_headSpecial->_next;
            delete _headSpecial;
            _headSpecial=temp;
        }
}
Node<Item>* Menue:: getItem(int i,Type type)
{
    /*Switch the correct item we want to order*/
    switch (type)
    {
        case special:return _headEdible->getNode(i);
        break;

        case beverage:return _headBeverage->getNode(i);
        break;

        case edible:return _headSpecial->getNode(i);
        break;

        default: return NULL;
        break;
    }

}
```

this is the function  `Node<Item>* Menue:: getItem(int i,Type type)` that use it in manue
if someone know how to fix it??

Comment: Where in your sample you're using a _smart pointer_ actually?

Comment: i try to understend who i can get back from node node<item>* i sending inherits bev or edible but i dont know who to solve it i want to know if smart poiner can solve it??

Comment: A `Node<Item>*`. One of the many problems is you're trying to return `Node<Edible>*` as a `Node<Item>*` and you can't. They are different things. You need to rethink your linked list implementation.

Comment: Smart pointer won't help you. A smart pointer of `Node<Item>` will still be different from a smart pointer to `Node<Edible>`.

Comment: but item is the base of edible and bevarage there is somthing that i can do batter??

Comment: A `Edible` can be used as an `Item` because of inheritance, but a `Node<Edible>` is a specialization of `Node`, not a subclass of `Node<Item>`. You can take the `Edible` out of the `Node` and return a pointer to the `Edible` as an `Item`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Node<Item>* Menue:: getItem(int i,Type type)
```

Cannot work because while `Beverage`, `Edible`, and `Special` may be sublasses of `Item`, a `Node<Item>` is different from a `Node<Beverage>`. `Node<Edible>` is a specialization of `Node`, not a subclass of `Node<Item>`, and cannot be used as a `Node<Item>`.

Fortunately the user of the Menu shouldn't care that there is a linked list of nodes hidden in there. All they want is an `Item`, and this can be provided without the `Node` wrapper.

```
Item * Menue:: getItem(int i,Type type)
{
    /*Switch the correct item we want to order*/
    switch (type)
    {
        case special:return _headEdible->getNode(i)->_item;
        break;

        case beverage:return _headBeverage->getNode(i)->_item;
        break;

        case edible:return _headSpecial->getNode(i)->_item;
        break;

        default: return NULL;
        break;
    }
}
```

This fixes the immediate problem, but not the underlying issue: OP does not understand enough of what they are doing to write a program of this complexity yet. The solution for that problem is read more of the textbook and do some of the problems or work through the examples to gain a better grasp on inheritance and pointers.

And then they should write the linked list of `Node`s again (`Node<T>::getNode`, for example, can easily run past the end of the list) testing it completely before moving on to writing the logic that depends on the linked list. Trying to write two pieces of a program at the same time often multiplies the number of bugs in Part A and Part B together rather than adding them for purposes of debugging time spent.

Comment: i understand but if i get the item i break the idea of shared pointer that was the main idea to start with all of that . i need the wrapper to know when to delete the pointer. i thought to use smart pointer because it can use template like that but still i don't know how

Comment: In this case you know the index of the node, so you could write your remove function to remove Node at index. You could also search and delete, but you cannot mix pointers to `Node`s of different types without another trick. Make a class `BaseNode` that your templated `Node` inherits from. Then you can pass any type of `Node` as a `BaseNode`, this probably overcomplicates things though. For one thing, how do you know which of your three lists to remove a `BaseNode` from?

Comment: there is a counter that count amount of use to  give adynamic option to remove adish from the menue but still the adress of the node is inside bills that use it when thay finsh thay need to remove one from counter until it will be zero then delete this noede . i just want to understend if i use a smart pointer it can solve this problem or how i can do it currectly??

Comment: who to use this function                                                             operator Node<T>() // implicit conversion ops.
 {                                                                                            return Node<T>(this);
        }

Comment: finialy secces i change the node to be item in the menue